# keep the index of a cascade ttk.combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, ttk

I do not believe this is a simple question so please take a think before answering.
I have 2 python tkinter ttk comboboxes and they cascade meaning you have to make a selection in the first before it populates the second.   so....  if I have say 4 elements in the first box and they each had 4 elements then the index of the last one would be 16.  my problem is that tk.combobox assigns a new index to each box starting with 0 and the best I can get is an index of 4.  I have tried many things with the value= and the textvariable= options and I have passed dictionaries, lists with indexes in the proper ranges (list[12:16]) and have asked the box for all sorts of indexes and they all start at 0 and count the elements in the second box from 0.  maybe this is the way.....  idk.  Oh, ya,  the reason I need the index to belong to the data is because I got the data from a database and the index is the key to the record so it has to be preserved.    If yall do not have an answer then I will have to take the text I can get and select it back from the databse to get the key.  I know this sounds simple  so maybe I will,  but I would like to keep the calls to the DB to min where possible.

there is no code for this because I am not looking to have code fixed.  i need to know how to give a tk. combobok values like (12:one,13:two,14:three) and when "two" is selected i need the number 13 not 1. ( and likely also do not want the index displayed in the box)
thank you for reading and any answers to my question.
** seems I must add a minimum amount of code so here goes.

```
   `import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    win = tk.Tk()
    list = (get some records from the database here with indexes)
    value = tk.StrinVar()
    box = ttk.Combobox(win, value=list, textvariable=value)
    box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", dosomething())
    box.grid(col=0,row=0)
    def dosomething(event):
        (get my original index here and process further using it)`
```

the default to tkinter combobox is to ignore the index in list and count from 0 when selected.  please do not comment on typos this is minimum for the board.  this is the default condition of an Access combobox,  is there maybe a better library besides tkinter?

Comment: Could you just do `4*first_index + second_index` to get an overall index from 0-15?

Comment: We'all need to see some code in the form of a [mre]. Please add one to your question.

Comment: the indexes may not be sequential, and there could be duplicates as it is categorizing items and the first level could be say office equipment and the second category could be paper and also there might be a top category of wood and the next may also be paper for cardboard.   as it is now the second category must be unique to be able to go back and search the table for its index.   I have done a lot of searching, it is ok if this cant be done, just hoping some coding wizard knew it off the top of his head.  many combo boxes have this feature TKinter may not have implemented it.

Comment: I have decided to use menus instead of comboboxes because I can set my own key fields

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to write a addition  either a class or function that takes a dictionary and uses the  values for the combobox and then returns the selected key.  The tkinter widget only returns an index from 0...to selected.
my solution is:

```
    def ebox(self, index=None, row=None, column=None, vals=None):
        self.set_var(key=index) #this just creates a tk.StringVar
        lis = []
        for item in vals: #converts a dictionary to a list of keys
            lis.append(item)
        self.combos[index] = ttk.Combobox(self.win, values=lis, textvariable=self.value[index])
        self.combos[index].bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event, y=vals: self.eboxclk(event, y))
        self.combos[index].grid(row=row, column=column)
        return

    def eboxclk(self, event=None, index=None):
        print(event.widget.get(), " the selected value ")
        print(index[event.widget.get()], " the index of the selected value")
        return index[event.widget.get()]
```

this can likely be simplified, it only took me many days of searching all the various black holes I went down to resolve it this far.